# Search static blocks in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is it possible to search for all static blocks in the code of a java project using Eclipse IDE ?

```
public class ExampleClass {

  static 
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: You can search using regex (CTRL + H) so you can write a simple regex to match the word `static` and `{` after it. (Possible in a newline)

Comment: Why don't you use the shortcut Ctrl + H and look for the word 'static'? Addationaly activate the option for case sensive search.

Comment: In case you need something that will always detect the static block, and it's something you will reuse often, you might check how the PMD rules for empty static initializer is written, and create your own rule adapted to your needs, so you can integrate it with PMD...

Comment: @reporter Because I need only the static blocks, I don't need the static variables, methods and classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the regular expression `static\s*\{`

This expression works even if the curly brace is on the subsequent line, as shown in your example.

**Details:**

- Use menu item *Search>Search...*
- In the dialog that appears:

  - In the field *Containing text*, enter `static\s*\{`
  - Click the *Regular expression* checkbox.
  - Under *File name patterns*, put `*.java`.